# sqlldr not found when using SQL*Loader in a shell script

Tags: sql, shell, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-loader

I would like to create shell script, *AUTOLOAD* that will, when ran, execute SQL*Loader with a set of instructions. All this is in my Linux environment.

SQL*loader will then import data to SQL developer

```
#!/bin/sh
#
echo -------- SQL loader --------
# @echo; 
#
sqlldr username@server1/password control=/folder1/ctrl/loader.ctl log=/folder1/load/results.l
```

My shell script is located in root directory and this is where I will be calling other files from.
But it is giving me error when I try to run it:

```
- line 6: sqlldr: command not found
```

I don't know how to specify path to SQL*Loader, since I am on Linux.

I am new to this...so Be gentle :(

Comment: I'm confused. Which shell do you intend to use `sh` (Bourne shell) or `bash` (Bourne-Again SHell)?

Comment: I am trying to use sh

Comment: What does your `/home/<username>/.ora_profile` or `/home/<username>/.profile` have in them because you might not be setting your environment variables correctly...

Comment: Use a text edit (vi should be installed on Linux but emacs etc) to open them @Angelina.

Comment: I don't have full permissions to this server :(

Comment: You should still have read access to the home directory of the username you're using in order to try to load data @Angelina... if you don't something's seriously wrong with your Linux install. P.S. If you're replying to someone please use the `@` syntax otherwise they don't get notified.

Comment: ok so I found out where is my sqlldr.exe stored. it is in /opt.oracle/product/11gR2/db/bix/sqlldr.exe  So how do I specify this is shell script? @Ben

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
locate sqlldr
```

That should return something like

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlldr
```

Edit your ~/.profile and add at the bottom

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
PATH="$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin"
```

Then re-load your profile with `source ~/.profile` (or log out and log back in), and you should be good to go.

Comment: export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/11gR2/db PATH="$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin" It doesnt work when I do this: source ~/.profile

Comment: I got it. Thank you all glen and @Ben